# I'm Confused with Java NIO

Tags: java, nio

I'm confused with java nio buffers and `Files.write` if I can write with buffers and channels on file why do I need Files class.

What's difference between both of these working code examples.

```
String newData = "New String to write to file..." + System.currentTimeMillis();

Path path = Paths.get("C://data/nio-data2.txt");
try {
    Files.write(path,newData.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and

```
try {
    RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile("C://data/nio-data.txt", "rw");
    FileChannel channel = aFile.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(48);
    buf.clear();
    buf.put(newData.getBytes());

    buf.flip();

    while(buf.hasRemaining()) {
        channel.write(buf);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT

i want to ask one more question, is Channels.newOutputStream interrupt the thread when write to file or worked as a non-blocking

Comment: The `Files` class provides a higher level API that's easier to use. You rarely need to handle buffers and channels manually.

Comment: Its kind of like asking if I can use streams then why would I need arrays, foreach loops and iterators.

Comment: Given your examples it should be pretty obvious. 6 lines using `Files.write` and 15 lines using buffers and channels.

Comment: `Files` is a utilities class that allows a one-liner, where elsewhere one would write several code lines, that one probably wrote numerous times before. I remember many code snippets of peoply with loops and a byte array as buffer.

Comment: BTW `aFile.close()` and maybe `"w"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version with `Files` shorter and easier to understand.

Other version is more flexible. It is not very useful when you have only one file to write, but if you have many files in different storages it can save you some resources.

**EDIT**

Here is `Files.write` source code:

```
public static Path write(Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options)
    throws IOException
{
    // ensure bytes is not null before opening file
    Objects.requireNonNull(bytes);

    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(path, options)) {
        int len = bytes.length;
        int rem = len;
        while (rem > 0) {
            int n = Math.min(rem, BUFFER_SIZE);
            out.write(bytes, (len-rem), n);
            rem -= n;
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

As you can see it doesn't use NIO inside, only good old `OutputStream`.

**EDIT 2**

In fact `Files.newOutputStream` don't return `FileOutputStream` as I expected. It returns `OutputStream` defined in `Channels.newOutputStream` which use NIO inside.

Comment: It do the same job, but use different API. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Files.write(...)` use `OutputStream` instead of `RandomAccessFile.getChannel()`. it some different mechanisms, so better to google it for understand
2. `Files.write(...)` much shorter and incapsulate logic of writting to file
3. When you use such 'low' code, you need to look after many things. For example, in your example you didn't close your channel.

So, in conclusion, if you need to just write – better to use `Files` or another high-level API. If you need some 'additional' features during read/write, you need to use `RandomAccessFile` or `InputStream/OutputStream`